# Do unused imports lower your Angular application performance?

Tags: angular, performance, import

I was wondering, do unused imports affect your Angular app performance or are the import really made when used? In other words I'd like to know if I should add a tslint rule to detect and remove unused imports in my project.

Comment: it should be trivial, but it does have a slight impact and considered bad practice to have unsude imports

Comment: yes actually, unused imports impacts performance